# Proving a statement about $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am being asked to show if some functions are linear transformations like the following:

$T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $Tx = ...$

If I believe that this function is not a linear transformation can I make a choice for $n$ ? Or do I have to show for all $n$ there is a counter example?

Comment: Just show that $\forall X, Y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ , $T (X+Y) = T(X) + T(Y)$ and $T(\lambda X) = \lambda T(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the problem statement would specify ("for some n,..." or "for all integers n,..." etc.). If this is some kind of homework problem I would assume it means for all n.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It does not say for all n. But if I assume it does then I could choose say n = 2, and find my counter-example there?

Comment: No, if the statement is for all n then you either need to prove or disprove it for all n. As an analogy, imagine that I make the statement "all bagels are gross." For me to prove that statement, it wouldn't be enough for me to prove that sesame bagels are gross, I would need to show something more general.